# Coffeescript import and organization for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm building a Rails application that is almost entirely CoffeeScript upfront. The user will never wait for a page redirect because literally everything happens on the front page (a la Twitter).

Now I've had to put all of my CoffeeScript into one file because my jQuery onLoad is complex and, while in production it will be compiled to one JS file, in testing this is not the case.

How can I either import CoffeeScript from other files in development or organize my CoffeeScript so I'm not piling 500 lines into one file (when those 500 lines contain 5/6 distinct domains)?

I have used `import` in SCSS to do the same thing for my stylesheets, but CS is proving a bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

The asset pipeline allows you to require different files into one file, which keeps them separate in development and compiles them to one file in production. Check out the instructions on [Manifest files and Directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

Also, have you looked into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)? It can work in or outside of Rails and might be the sort of thing you need.